# how to use more than one foreign key in mapping django models

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have an appointment, person and office model. I am aware of using FOREIGN_KEY.to_field to match something other than pk, but how I do make it match the office_id too? I am using mysql and would prefer to minimize any architectural changes.

In other words, if I need appointment.person, then it should return appointment.person that has person.office = office.office_id.

[image: Imgur]

I believe this is about compounded keys in django and this is [not supported](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) by the ORM. There is something called the [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#unique-together) that I might be able to use, but still not sure how.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id    = models.IntegerField() # not pk
    office       = models.ForeignKey(Office)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointment_id    = models.IntegerField() # not pk
    office            = models.ForeignKey(Office)
    person            = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Office(models.Model):
    # mystuff here
```

Comment: What is your final goal? You want to restrict the creation of `Appointment` having person from another office than one in the the appointment? Then think about what will happen when some person changes his office? I believe you do not want to change the office of the appoinments that have past. If you don't want to track where an appointment was then you could remove the office FK from it, you have the person, so you have the office where an appointment is going to be? Or you want to make a query which will filter only the appointments which will be in the persons offices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you use person_id and pk in your Person model and pk and office_id in your Office model? The way I would do that:

```
class Office(models.Model):
    # office stuff here

class Person(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office)

class Apointment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
```

Since django autogenerate the pk for each model I don't see a reason to add those _id fields.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - You are right. It was a mistake on my drawing, and the way you have mentioned is how I have it.. drawing updated.

Comment: Humm I think you just have to change in Apointment class the field person to:
     person = models.ForeignKey(Person, to_field='person_id')

I never used but I found it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/

The unique_together that you refeer is only to make a UNIQUE KEY between two fields.